# Refresh webpage after postback was received

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, postback

I am using an Image processing API. (Blitline)

By the nature of it, image processing takes a while to complete. Let's say 3 - 6 seconds.

After submitting a job, the API returns immediately the future url of my procesed image, but for 3 - 6 seconds that url will return a 404, since the image has not yet finished proessing.

As soon as the job finishes, the Blitline service sends a Postback to a PHP script on my server, telling me it's done.

At this point, I want to show the processed image to the user.

Is there a technology that will load the image in the user browser at the time the postback comes in?

I know it could be done with Javascript polling. E.g. check every 2 seconds if the postback had come in yet.

But I wonder if there is a more modern way to do this?

Comment: yes websockets, if you don't want to build it yourself check out http://socketo.me/

Comment: Check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: For this use case, i would stick to ajax polling, sockets seem like overkill for a conection that only needs to stay open for a few seconds

Comment: I agree. The web socket and ratchet are interesting, but too heavy for my app.

Comment: I agree that polling may be a suitable approach here, but keep in mind that this will massively reduce the number of possible concurrent users.

Comment: Blitline has now changed their polling options. The recommend this:

   $.ajax({
       url: "http://cache.blitline.com/listen/[JOB_ID]",
       success: function(data) {
           alert("Got data=" + data)
       }
   });

And it works great. You mean such polling would reduce the amount of concurrent users?  They describe their polling here: http://www.blitline.com/docs/polling

Answer (score 1):

Another issue that has to be dealt with is S3 latency. Just because an image is uplaoded to S3 and S3 has responded that it got it, doesn't mean the image will be available publicly immediately. While it is generally available within a few milliseconds, this can extend into seconds sometimes.

Since you have the URL, you can just poll S3 for the image. Here is an example:

https://coderwall.com/p/hy_qjw

This example tries to load a hidden image from S3. If it succeeds, it tries again in a few seconds (you can adjust the setTimeout). This would work wether you are waiting for Blitline to finish, or waiting for S3 to make the image available.